# Mostrar consulta por fecha actual

Tags: java, mysql

Quisiera mostrar una consulta por la fecha actual, ya que cuando guardo en mi tabla tengo el campo `fecha` y es tipo `date`.

El formato para mostrar y guardar la fecha es éste:

```
void cargar() {

    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    int anio=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mesi=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int mest=mesi+1;
    int mes=mest;
    int dia=cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
    String fecha= anio+"-"+mes+"-"+dia;
    this.lab_fecha.setText(fecha);

}
```

Estoy haciendo la consulta así pero igual me sigue mostrando todas las fechas, y lo que quiero lograr es que me muestre sólo los registros que tengan fecha del día de hoy.

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM adelantos WHERE fecha ORDER BY fecha DESC,hora DESC";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que comparar la fecha de hoy con la fecha de los registros, pero tienes que dar a esta última el formato correcto.

```
SELECT *
FROM adelantos 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()
```

Comment: gracias me ha servido

Comment: @yoclens Si te ha servido como respuesta deberías marcarla como tal...

Answer (score 2):

En el where debes incluir la condicion

```
where fecha ="Alguna fecha"
```

debes corregirlo en tu consulta:

```
"SELECT * FROM adelantos WHERE fecha=now() ORDER BY fecha DESC,hora DESC";
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes incluir `now()` que refiere la fecha actual de tu servidor o tu maquina

```
SELECT * FROM adelantos WHERE fecha = now() ORDER BY fecha DESC,hora DESC
```